# @angular-devkit/core module not found after angular-cli global fresh install

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using npm, I have installed angular-cli globally, with the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

After installing it succesfully, every command including just `ng -v`, returns the same error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\btngtk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\btngtk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)?[39m
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)?[39m
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)?[39m
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)?[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\btngtk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\?[4m@angular?[24m\cli\lib\init.js:13:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)?[39m
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)?[39m
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)?[39m
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)?[39m
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ?[32m'C:\\Users\\btngtk\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\init.js'?[39m,
    ?[32m'C:\\Users\\btngtk\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng'?[39m
  ]
}
```

Comment: `@angular-devkit` is required by `@angular/cl`i as dependency maybe something went wrong with npm install. Maybe try `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, then clear the npm cache with `npm cache clean` and then retry the installation.

Comment: I tried that several times, with npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and deleting physically npm and npm-cache directories

Comment: What's you node.js version?

Comment: The latest one, 12.4.0 , but prior to that I tried with the 10.16.0 with the same result.

Comment: Thx @youri, it works. It's just that I had to add `--force` when cleaning the cache. `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @coldistric, thanks, I posted it as a answer to help others!

Answer (score 2):

`@angular-devkit` is required by `@angular/cli` as dependency maybe something went wrong with npm install.

So uninstall `@angular/cli` with:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then clear the npm cache with:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then retry the installation.