# can't run brand new angular project

Tags: angular-cli

First of all, YES, I did my research. I wen't through suggested 'Similar questions' here on stackoverflow and I googled two days in a row. I wasn't able to fix this problem yet.

*The problem:*

On my new PC I recently installed **node.js**, **typescript** and **Angular**.

I created a new project (let's call the app ***reminder***) like so

```
ng new reminder --style scss --prefix rem --routing
```

Immediately I try to run it, just to make sure it works

```
ng serve
```

And this is what I get back

> An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for
>   builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server

I've been looking for a solution since the day before yesterday - I tried to install the devkit/build-angular dev-server manually. I also tried multiple other things I found, but neither worked so far...

Any ideas, anybody?

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.0
@angular/cli                      8.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               8.1.0
@schematics/update                0.801.0
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

**THESE ARE JUST A FEW THINGS AMONG EVERYTHING I TRIED AND DIDN'T WORK:**

```
// reinstall angular cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli


// manually install devkit/build
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular


// reinstalled everything
uninstalled angular
uninstalled typescript
removed node
installed fresh node from nodejs.org
npm cache clean --force
npm chache verify
npm install @angular/cli --global
```

**UPDATE:**
I uninstalled angular/cli 8 and installed angular/cli 7.3.5 back as it was.
Now the server works.
I'll wait for an answer to this question.

Comment: Assuming that the something might have left. I think it would be better if you put what you have tried.

Comment: Did you try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56873555/3371440

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: @Flash `@angular-devkit` is required by `@angular/cli`, no need to install it manually if `@angular/cli` is correctly installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@angular-devkit/core module not found after angular-cli global fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772483/angular-devkit-core-module-not-found-after-angular-cli-global-fresh-install)

Comment: reinstall angular/cli and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this for over a week,
but none of the suggested (or googled) solutions worked.

I ended up 'reseting' my PC:
settings -> recovery -> reset this PC

After clean Windows, npm and Angular installs everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333128)):

> ```
> $ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> $ npm cache clean
> $ npm install -g @angular/cli
> ```
>
> Install `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as dev dependency. This
> package is newly introduced in `Angular 6.0`
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
>
> or,
>
> yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which version of node and angular cli you have installed? You can find this by typing on a console:

```
node --version
ng --version
```

What do you mean by installing typescript? That's not required. All you have to do is install NodeJS and Angular CLI globally.

You could try to generate a default project, just to check your setup. The instructions can be found on the Angular website:
https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: my node version is v10.16.0, my Angular version is 8.1.0

Comment: Have you tried generating a new app following the Angular guide mentioned before?

Comment: yes, I did. although I doubt it made any difference. anyway, it results in the same error.